# trying to override AppRegistryNotReady in standalone Django

Tags: python, django

I'm experimenting with standalone script with Django, inherited from https://github.com/syntarsus/minimal-django

When I leave invoking a development server to command line call things go well:

```
python minimal.py runserver
```

the server is happily up and running:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 24, 2017 - 00:58:36
Django version 1.11.5, using settings None
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I wanted to modify the script to go a level down in Django abstractions and invoke the server with:

```
from django.core import management    
management.call_command('runserver')
```

this throws exception

```
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

As suggested in other SO questions, I tried overriding ths exception with:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

...but apparently it is not working again, so I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me, invoke by simply doing `python minimal.py` and it will run a local server:

**minimal.py**

```
import sys

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.http import HttpResponse

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='A-random-secret-key!',
    ROOT_URLCONF=sys.modules[__name__],
)
django.setup()


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>A minimal Django response!</h1>')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index),
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_command('runserver')
```

Comment: Works for me, I just want to mention better use commnad line to run the script as IDE(Spyder) just hangs on it.